# Iterating using pointers works only on half of an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have got problem with my program. I need to iterate over a two-dimensional array and operate on its values (actually it is a .pgm image). Double *for* loops works great, but I wanted to use pointers. So I tried something like this:

```
#define MAX 256
.
. 
.
void blur(int table[][MAX], int x_size, int y_size){
   int *ptr = table;
   for(int i=0;i<x_size*y_size;i++)
      ptr[i]= (int) ((1/3)*(ptr[i-1]+ptr[i]+ptr[i+1]))
}
```

And it works only for half of an array. Multiplying x_size*y_size by 2 solves the problem, but isn't it a bad practice?

By the way, this function should blur given picture horizontally. Is it correct?

Comment: If your table is `[Y][MAX]` the problem is probably that `x_size < MAX` so you better do two loops.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie yes, true.

Comment: (1/3) is zero by the way.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
void blur(int table[][MAX], int x_size, int y_size)
```

the `table` in `blur` is a pointer to arrays of `int`, each of the size `MAX`. I'm not sure this is what you want, but if your array is indeed shaped that way, you'll have `MAX - x_size` *unused* entries in every "row". If you just try to access entries by an `int` pointer and an offset, you will access these unused entries as well.

---

Apart from that, a conversion from `int (*)[MAX]` (pointer to an array of `int`, this is what you actually pass to your function) to `int *` (pointer to `int`) is not correct and not allowed. So better forget about your idea entirely.

Answer (score 0):

As Felix points out, your approach is not correct. Consider the following approach:

```
int matrix_main(void)
{
    int *matrix= malloc(x_size*y_size*sizeof(int));
    //
    // now fill matrix (not shown)
    //
    // now blur it
    blur(matrix, x_size, y_size);
    //...
}
void blur(int *ptr, int x_size, int y_size){
   for(int i=0;i<x_size*y_size-1;i++)
      ptr[i]= (int) ((1/3.0)*(ptr[i-1]+ptr[i]+ptr[i+1]))
}
```

Note that algorithmaticly speaking, you are processing each pixel muliple times. Maybe better to create a new matrix. Then you can properly process it as a blur of all surrounding pixels.